# Keras multi input : MLP model with different scale inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm at the point in which, for my thesis, I need to provide (or at least try) a predictive model for the experimental data I gathered. 
Since the FEM analysis for the system is very complex, I thought to give a MLP (or any other more appropriate ML algo) a try.

Basically I have different batches (denoted by fixed V,U for each) of len(tv).

The inputs are (example with voltage=V, viscosity=U):

```
time vector : tv = np.arange(0.0995 , 7.0995, 0.1)
voltage : v = np.full(len(tv), V)
viscosity : u = np.full(len(tv), U)
dimensions : [x, y, z, diameter]
```

I have 4 inputs for each batch: the first three have the same len, the last one has len=4.

The output is a vector of len(tv) with Gaussian shape : each value is corresponding to a value from the tv vector

- How would you model the MLP layers (if this is a good way to start) with Keras?
- Since the data has different scales, I need to rescale/normalize it, which would be a good approach? Subtracting the first value of each array (making it zero based) or for example rescaling it between -1,1 ?

Thank you!